# pgfgantt: Change Link style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm using the `pgfgantt` package to draw Gantt-Charts. Everything works except for one things: I can not change the style of the links. The [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJN9h.png) shows on page 29 the following example:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, link/.style={-latex, red}]{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{2}{3} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{2}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{6}{11} \\
\ganttbar{Task 4}{8}{11}
\ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem0}{elem1}
\ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink[link type=f-f]{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
```

According to the documentation, this should lead to:

[image: Should be]

If I compile this code, I only get:

[image: Is]

I can put whatever style definition I want into the `link\.style` but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is different, according to the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf):

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, link={-latex,red}]{12}
```

However, it works with `link/.style`. Minimal example, I chose even other styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
  \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, link/.style={-stealth, thick,blue}]{12}
    \gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{2}{3} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2}{2}{5} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 3}{6}{11} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 4}{8}{11}
    \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{elem0}{elem1}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{elem1}{elem2}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-f]{elem2}{elem3}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Gantt chart]

If you dont't get this result

- Check your other code, which you did not show
- Update your packages, pgf/TikZ and pgfgantt